# Angular4 OAuth2 IdentityServer4

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm looking at creating an Angular4 WebApp that will have a login/sign up page for users. I need it to be able to have:

- Custom Login (i.e. users configured there own Username/Password)
- Google Login
- Facebook Login

So far my understanding is that I will need the following:

- Client (my Angular4 web app)
- Auth Server (IdentityServer4?)
- Resource server (ASP.NET Core Web Api)

If I utilise something like IdentityServer4 as my auth server. I wouldn't be able to have my Login/Signup form embedded in the app? I would have to always redirect to the AuthServer to perform the login and then redirect back to my Client along with the access token. Which is a user experience we don't really want but I'm not aware of an alternative?

My questions are:

1. Am I correct that my Angular4 app can't have a Login/Signup page if I use IdentityServer4. It must be redirected and performed on the AuthServer itself
2. Is there an alternative I can use instead of IdentityServer4 for creating Login/Signup with an Angular web app based on my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IdentityServer for the front-end of login forms is completely optional. I suggest reading up on [the various Flows that are supported](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html). The simplest (often called "legacy" and insecure) option to understand is the Resource Owner Password flow, which is one of the flows that allows a pure JavaScript solution for getting and using tokens, using a form of your own creation.

To answer your questions directly:

1. No, you are not correct. Flows with redirection are just one of the options, flows without (with just a form in your own app) are also possible.
2. Yes, there are probably alternatives, but Stack Overflow isn't great/intended for recommendations. You might want to check [SoftwareRecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (read their FAQ though!) for investigating that.